# What NIC for a NUC?

Tags: penetration-test, wireless

I have been doing external pentests using the Intel NUC (D34010WYK1).  It has been a very stable machine running Kali Linux.

I am at point now that I would like to do some wireless testing.  Has anyone used the NUC for wireless testing?

If you have experience with this setup, please respond with NUC model, NIC model and the tools you have used.

Thanks

Comment: NIC-NUC paddy-whack, give a dog a bone...

Comment: Any Atheros-based card would do (from experience I can say they have the best Linux support ever). I don't know what this "NUC" has inside, but if it has any kind of removable mini-PCI(e) slot you can just buy an Atheros card and put it in there. But isn't a laptop better for wireless pentesting ?

Comment: @Andre - The NUC is a full blown Intel PC.  Kali runs great on it, its small, silent and relatively inexpensive.  If I can get wireless working well, it would make a great drop box solution.  Atheros does seem like the right chipset.  I ordered a NIC today.  Will update once it has been tested.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a NUC but if you want to do wireless testing you'll want a card capable of packet injection and promiscuous mode. I use the Alfa AWUS036H card (you may want to get a newer model) with kali linux and have no problems. From there you'll want to use the aircrack-ng suite of tools at minimum.

Comment: I have an Alfa usb NIC but it doesn't seem to play well with the NUC

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right, you are fairly limited in the choice of wireless NICs for a NUC to begin with. I have a NUC, but never installed a wireless NIC. I would go with the one Intel recommends (which is, not surprisingly, an Intel NIC).

Of course, you can also always use a USB NIC.

Comment: The reasearch I've done on the Intel NIC has lead to reliabilty concerns.